# Flutter - Best way to do real-time messaging app with notifications per received message?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, real-time, messaging

I've made a Flutter messaging app with Firestore that works by giving each user a list of received messages and triggering a function every time this list is updated and displaying it using a StreamBuilder. **It's not a chatting app**. It's a one-message send app but I want it to work in real-time.

The list thing isn't working as expected. It behaves oddly and the messages come unsorted and there are too many problems to manage.

Is there a more correct way of implementing such an app?

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e

Seems working very well with firebase.